# Qt5 can not start application out of the IDE

Tags: qt, mingw, qt-creator

I'm working on a program with Qt 5.5 in the IDE Qt Creator 3.4.2 (Community). The program can be started normally in the IDE, but when I try to double-click the .exe file, it says

> Cannot find the entry point for the procedure __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length in library D:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\Qt5Test.dll

and

> Cannot find the entry point for the procedure __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length in library D:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\Qt5Core.dll

I have added

> D:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin;D:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin;

to my environmental variable.

Any ideas about what's wrong?

Comment: You can try windeployqt.exe

Answer (score 0):

I think currently your program is using dlls from the folders:

> D:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin;D:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin;

And the correct one is:

> D:\Qt\Qt5.5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\

(Make sure it is correct on your machine)

This is the one Qt Creator is using. You need to add it to PATH before mingw path or copy dlls you need from it to your folder with your exe.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, libstdc++-6.dll is needed